# Why JavaScript declared variable is in the global object before initialization?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, scope, global-variables

I've stumbled upon a JavaScript variable behavior I could not explain.

According to [JS docs on var keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) :

> The scope of a variable declared with var is the enclosing function
>   or, for variables declared outside a function, the global scope (which
>   is bound to the global object).

Also it is known that global variables become properties of the global object - 'window' in the browser environments and 'global' in node.js
This means if a variable is declared with a 'var' keyword inside a function it becomes local and does not get into the global object.

This example proves it:

```
(function(){
    var t = 1;
    console.log(t in window, t); // outputs: false 1
}());
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/WmH77/)

So far so good. However if variable is not initialized it does become a property of the window object despite the fact it is in the function scope.

```
(function(){
    var t;
    console.log(t in window, t); // outputs: true undefined
}());
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/WmH77/1/)

Why does it happen ? Where can I learn the details of this behavior ? Regular tutorials don't seem to cover this.

Thanks in advance.

[EDIT]:
Thanks to the Pointy it is clear now scope works as expected. I simply had a wrong understanding of the 'in' operator behavior. According to ['in' docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) it coerces left hand operand to the number or string and looks for such index or property name in the right hand object.
So in the example one it was equal to

```
'1' in window
```

which was false

and in the example two it was

```
'undefined' in window
```

which was true.

Comment: The variable is still there... it just doesn't have a value.  `var a; console.log(typeof a);` will be undefined no matter where you put it.

Comment: I shall now name all my variables after African countries for the day.

Comment: Ha ha @DaveNewton actually I was confused, but I confess that that's been a standard diagnostic test I've employed for years in "WTF" situations :-)

Comment: @Brad undefined value is predictable. The question is why the variable is global at the declaration time and becomes local only after initialization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that your test code is using the `in` operator erroneously. What it's actually testing is whether the name "undefined" is defined in `window`, not "t".  Why? Because the left-hand operand of `in` is coerced to a string. Because "t" is `undefined`, it's coerced to the string "undefined", and indeed that property name is present in the global context.

Change the test to

```
console.log("t" in window, t);
```

Comment: Your suggestion seems to be valid. Thanks a lot. I was totally puzzled and was thinking something was wrong with the scope but the reason was my wrong understanding of the 'in' operator.

Answer (score 2):

access to a variable declared by

```
var t;
```

gives you:

```
console.log(t);
undefined

console.log(undefined === t)
true
```

undefined is a property of window

```
console.log(undefined in window);
```